# Feature Points Shapefile missing Spatial Reference Information

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, coordinate-system

I'm working with ArcMap 10 and I have a feature points shapefile from the Florence (Italy) municipality open data (http://opendata.comune.fi.it/statistica_territorio/dataset_0040.html). Each point is an address point.

As I add it to the data frame a message says the data is missing spatial reference information and the points result in a wrong location. How can I understand which is the correct spatial reference of this shapefile and have the points in the correct location? I own other features of the same area with the correct coordinates (eg a layer with the streets of Florence). Coordinates system of these features is GCS_WGS_1984 Would that be of any use?

I followed these steps http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0111/tip.html but couldn't get it working. I hope I didn't miss any older post posing this question. In case I did I apologize.

Comment: The dataset has a .prj, but it doesn't look like a legal Esri PRJ string to me (too many extras).  Since it claims to be EPSG 3003, why not just rename the .prj to .prx, and define with 3003?

Comment: Melita says that the "semi_minor" parameter is causing the parser to fail -- if you remove the `PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356911.95],` the .prj  file should be readable.

Comment: Probably ought to tell the provider that their data isn't formatted correctly, too.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately my knowledge of geodetic systems (I don't really know the meaning of EPSG 3003) and file formats is quite limited. How could I remove that part? Which program should I use to do this and save it again as a .prj?

Comment: The .prj is a text file -- **any** text editor can be used (just be sure to leave it as one long string)

Comment: Now the data seems to be in the right location. I just need to understand which the correct transformation for this zone from GCS_WSG_1984 to PCS Monte Mario / Italy Zone 1 and viceversa, in order to have streets and point in the same CS.